# Windows Authentication Working For Some But Not Others

Tags: windows, authentication, ntlm

I have a web application hosted via IIS that requires windows authentication.  Some users are able to access the applicaiton with no problems.  Others get a dialog requesting credentials, but when they cancel the request, the application loads correctly.  Still others are prompted for credentials and when they enter them, they get a 401 error.  Using Fiddler, I've found that the authentication header for users that works looks like this:

```
-[NTLM Type3: Authentication]------------------------------
Provider: NTLMSSP
Type: 3
OS Version: 6.1:7601
Flags:  0xe2888215
    Unicode supported in security buffer.
    Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
    Sign (integrity)
    NTLM authentication.
    Negotiate Always Sign.
    Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
    Target Information block provided for use in calculation of the NTLMv2 response.
    Supports 56-bit encryption.
    Supports 128-bit encryption.
    Client will provide master key in Type 3 Session Key field.
lmresp_Offset: 136; lmresp_Length: 24; lmresp_Length2: 24
ntresp_Offset: 160; ntresp_Length: 24; ntresp_Length2: 24
Domain_Offset: 88; Domain_Length: 16; Domain_Length2: 16
User_Offset: 104; User_Length: 14; User_Length2: 14
Host_Offset: 118; Host_Length: 18; Host_Length2: 18
msg_len: 184
Domain: XXX
User: YYY
Host: ZZZ
```

Users that are prompted for their credentials (but the application still loads) look like this:

```
-[NTLM Type3: Authentication]------------------------------
Provider: NTLMSSP
Type: 3
OS Version: 5.1:2600
Flags:  0xa2888205
    Unicode supported in security buffer.
    Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
    NTLM authentication.
    Negotiate Always Sign.
    Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
    Target Information block provided for use in calculation of the NTLMv2 response.
    Supports 56-bit encryption.
    Supports 128-bit encryption.
lmresp_Offset: 118; lmresp_Length: 24; lmresp_Length2: 24
ntresp_Offset: 142; ntresp_Length: 24; ntresp_Length2: 24
Domain_Offset: 72; Domain_Length: 16; Domain_Length2: 16
User_Offset: 88; User_Length: 12; User_Length2: 12
Host_Offset: 100; Host_Length: 18; Host_Length2: 18
msg_len: 166
Domain: XXX
User: VVV
Host: WWW
lm_resp: 11 E3 1E 09 74 1E 9B 8A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
nt_resp: 98 BF FC 1C BF 65 EE 46 6A 71 26 5E 14 5D 34 CA 1F 1A E2 4A 00 1D BC 58
------------------------------------
```

The headers look very similar but, for the case that isn't working, the following flags are missing:

- Sign (integrity)
- Client will provide master key in Type 3 Session Key field

I've been googling for a couple of days and I can't seem to determine where these keys are coming from!  Is this related to a browser setting?  An account setting?  An IIS setting?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? 

I've a similar problem, just the legacy web page authentication isn't working when "Sing (integrity)" and "Client will provide master key in Type 3 Session Key field." authentication request messages are present.